# Selectbox on chrome doesn't work

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I made a style selector which changes site from boxed to wide and from wide to boxed. It works on all browsers, but on Chrome doesn't. When I click on option from selectbox nothing happens.

This is a part of HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/boxed.css" id="layout">

   <select>
        <option class="boxed">Boxed</option>
        <option class="wide">Wide</option>
    </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
    // Layout Changer
    $(".wide" ).click(function(){
        $("#layout" ).attr("href", "css/wide.css" );
        return false;
    });

    $(".boxed" ).click(function(){
        $("#layout" ).attr("href", "css/boxed.css" );
        return false;
    });
```

Cheers!

Comment: I didn't think `option`s had a click handler. You should wait for onchange of the select, and then check its value.

Comment: @arxanas is correct. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't the `id` tag. It's the `click` handler. Try this:

JavaScript:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#style_switcher").on('change', function() {
        $('#layout').attr('href', $(this).val() + '.css');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<link id="layout" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wide.css">

<select id="style_switcher">
    <option value="wide">Wide</option>
    <option value="boxed">Boxed</option>
</select>
```

You can also check out this plugin and make it easy for yourself: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/styleswitch/toggle.html